# show question or answer version of comment time

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometime comments seem to be very weird and not matching the question/answer until you recognize that the answer/question text has been changed after the comment was posted. It would be nice to have

a) a marker that shows, how much edits has been done since the comment was posted
b) a link on this marker, that shows the question/answer of the time the comment was posted

For example this comment got 77 upvotes, it is still valuable but confuses because `del` is not mentioned in the answer: [How to remove a key from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary#comment26848760_11277439)

Comment: If a comment no longer makes sense because of changes in the post, just flag it as “no longer needed” so it can be deleted.

Comment: this comment got 77 upvotes, is still valuable but confuses, because `del` is not mentioned in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary#comment26848760_11277439 so I would not say its no longer needed, but the context should be recognized, or maybe it should be rephrased, but then it cannot just keep the upvotes

Comment: Votes on comments are not relevant to decide if they merit deletion. If the comment is no longer relevant in the context of the post, is by definition _no longer needed_. If you think there is valuable content that shouldn’t be lost, post it in an answer.

Comment: @yivi: No, don't flag the comment, it is as relevant now as it ever was, the answer before and after the edit used `pop`. The comment mentions `del` because that is what is used in the question.

Comment: I haven’t read that comment nor that question. I’m not talking about a specific case, but the general rule: if a comment no longer makes sense under a post, it’s no longer needed. @user000001

Comment: @yivi maybe you should read it, because the comment is still a valuable addition, just why it starts with a reference to `del`, which hasnt been mentioned before is weird

Answer (score 3):

While there may be some value of such feature to make moderating/flagging comments easier I don't think it is required and not really worth dev effort to be added to the site.

What actions are already available now to deal with such comments:

- If question/answer updated according to comment (like "you've misspelled `whille`") then comment should be flagged "no longer needed" and will be removed.
- If answer significantly edited but still answers original question - again flag comment as "no longer needed"
- If question is significantly/completely changed to the point it ask new unrelated question - roll back such edit and potentially flag for moderator attention (especially if you find user doing it more than once on different question or starter edit war on that question).